# How to add `imenu` support to a major mode that does not support it and issue and error?

Tags: major-mode, imenu

When working with YANG files using the [yang-mode](https://github.com/mbj4668/yang-mode) I get a [imenu-unavailable "The mode ‘YANG//l’ does not support Imenu](https://github.com/mbj4668/yang-mode/issues/9) error.

The `yang-mode` derives from `prog-mode` which I believe requires `imenu` support.

How can I add `imenu` support for yang-mode in my system without modifying yang-mode code and not being affected by the error thrown by execution of the `yang-mode` code?

**More specifically**: is it possible to add imenu support to a failing major mode *outside* of the major mode definition code that fails *because* it invokes a derived mode that expects imenu support to be present?

Or is the only option to fix the original definition of that major mode by setting `imenu-generic-expression` to a valid/expected imenu   list of (MENU-TITLE REGEXP INDEX) entries?

Comment: See library `imenu.el`, especially `imenu-generic-expression`. For an example of defining Imenu support for a major mode see library `outline.el`. See the definition of `outine-mode` and that mode's value of `imenu-generic-expression`.

Comment: I was not specific enough in my question.  I will add details.

Comment: @Drew, I can add support to that specific mode, but the mode function fails before running my hook.  If I put the code early inside the mode function I'm able to get it to work.  But that means modifying the original code.  I will submit my changes but wanted to know if I could circumvent the error in the meantime without replacing the mode function.

Comment: `prog-mode` does not "require imenu support" to my knowledge.  `prog-mode` exists mostly so that `prog-mode-hook` can be useful, and to set a very small number of buffer-local values which are expected to be common across programming languages.  It does nothing else at all.  Where did you read that imenu support was required?

Comment: I might not have described it properly.  The yang-mode code generates an error early when `run-hook` which eventually *calls* `(imenu-add-to-menubar)` which signals a imenu-unavailable error.  If I setq `imenu-generic-expression` to a valid list early into the yang-mode code, before the eval of ``(c-initialize-cc-mode t)`` I solve the problem.  I have not been able to solve it from *outside* of that yang-mode code.

Comment: Looking at your error, a function `imenup-add-defs-to-menubar` is being called.  Despite the name, that's not part of Emacs at all, so I think the issue is with your config.  You probably want to find out what's defining that function and how it's being used -- it sounds like a bad assumption is being made somewhere.

Comment: @phils Thanks.  You are correct.  The error is caused by imenu+ or my use of it.  Without it, the error is not generated if I remove my setting of the `imenu-generic-expression` from `yang-mode` code.

Comment: Where are you invoking `imenup-add-defs-to-menubar`? If you're not the author of `yang-mode`, and if you're invoking that function from `yang-mode-hook`, then it's no wonder that an error is raised. That function expects `imenu-generic-expression` to be defined in the mode where you invoke it. See the example of `(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook ...)` in `imenu+.el`: it first sets `imenu-generic-expression` and then invokes `imenup-add-defs-to-menubar`. IOW, you should not need to change the mode code - just use its hook to do what you want.

Comment: @Drew I'mnot the author of yang-mode. What I ended up doing to solve the issue was to put the call to ``imenup-add-defs-to-menubar`` inside an ``ignore-errors`` form to prevent the error in yang-mode to stop the processing and then my hook was able to set up ``imenu-generic-expression`` and the other code I wanted.

Comment: I assume you're using a custom `prog-mode-hook` to run imenu things generally?  It sounds like you just need to check the value of `imenu-generic-expression` in your custom code, and act conditionally based on that result?

Comment: @phils For setting up imenu+, yes I was (and still am) setting the imenu+ in the prog-mode-hook.  I was not protecting against the signal it raised under the condition Drew described.  Now I protect against that by enclosing my code in a ``ignore-error` form to protect.  And in this specific case I setup the imenu variable specifically for yang-mode and I do it in the yang-mode-hook along with other things.  imenu+ is activated conditionally and independently of yang-mode by my system (which drives everything from customization to help people that don't know/want to program in elisp).

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with this question.  The issue was an error in code invoked via a mode hook.  The solution was to prevent the raising of the error in the function used in the hook.  Should I just say that?  Or remove the question?

Comment: As there are no answers, you're free to rewrite the question to be something different, so I suggest you do that.  Change it to better describe the nature of the problem, and then post your own answer with the solution you ended up with.